# Set count to variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I would like to assign the number of rows of my table to a variable.

```
DECLARE @ROW_COUNT nvarchar(1000);
SET @sql_row_count = 'SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ' + @TABLE_NAME;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql_row_count, @ROW_COUNT OUTPUT;

SET @ROW_COUNT = cast(@ROW_COUNT as int);
SELECT @ROW_COUNT;
```

@ROW_COUNT returns null.

Thank for help.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: It ist sql-server.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Comments on your existing query

1. `@ROW_COUNT` should be integer. You don't need to use `CAST()` if you defined it as integer.
2. You need to assign `@ROW_COUNT` to `COUNT(*)`.
3. use `QUOTENAME()` on the @TABLE_NAME to avoid sql injection.
4. define the parameters for `sp_executesql`.

Modified query as follow

---

```
DECLARE @ROW_COUNT INT;
DECLARE @sql_row_count NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET @sql_row_count = 'SELECT @ROW_COUNT = COUNT(*) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(@TABLE_NAME);

-- print out for verification
PRINT @sql_row_count 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql_row_count, N'@ROW_COUNT INT OUTPUT', @ROW_COUNT OUTPUT;

-- SET @ROW_COUNT = cast(@ROW_COUNT as int);
SELECT @ROW_COUNT;
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to alter the dynamic query by adding a variable that will
be assigned the value Count(*) and change the call sp_executesql by adding a description of this variable.

```
Declare @ROW_COUNT Int;
Declare @TABLE_NAME sysname = 'TableName';
Declare @sql_row_count nVarChar(max);
SET @sql_row_count = 'SELECT @ROW_COUNT=COUNT(*) FROM ' + 
@TABLE_NAME;
EXEC sp_executesql @sql_row_count, N'@ROW_COUNT Int OUTPUT', 
@ROW_COUNT=@ROW_COUNT OUTPUT

SELECT @ROW_COUNT;
```

Comment: A good answer explains the solution in addition to providing working code.

Comment: For safety you should be making use of `QUOTENAME`.